# The Witcher 3, "Odrin and Friends - Bottlemen" merchant not working

Tags: the-witcher-3

In theory, there is this merchant at the north side of the Novigrad island who is supposed to buy your things at the price that appears in the inventory. Yet for some reason it appears as a normal merchant who buys stuff at a lower price. Why does this happen? Am I supposed to do something for this merchant to work?

Comment: This might have been a bug and has been fixed in the meantime. Where did you learn about this merchant?

Comment: A friend who has the game told me, plus I have seen other posts mentioning this same merchant.

Answer (score 2):

This king of behavior is usually considered as an exploit and not intended to be in the game. Can't find an exact patch which fixed that, but it was fixed as the famous cow and sea shell bugs too. I just checked in-game - the merchant is there and buying items with lower than value prices, selling just empty bottles.

Comment: Well, that's a shame. So I guess there are no merchants left in the game who will buy stuff to its full value?

Comment: No, this was not intended by design.